# Meteor-angular autocomplete from huge data

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I have angular-meteor app that needs Material md-autocomplete from a collection with 53,296 documents with `angularUtils.directives.dirPagination` but this amount of data make my browser hang.

I'm publishing the collection with:

```
Meteor.publish('city', function (options, searchString) {
  var where = {
    'city_name': {
      '$regex': '.*' + (searchString || '') + '.*' ,
      '$options': 'i'
    }
  };
  return City.find(where, options);
});
```

I subscribe with:

```
subscriptions: function () {
  Meteor.subscribe('city');
  this.register('city', Meteor.subscribe('city'));
}
```

and have pagination on controller :

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.pageSize = 100;
$scope.sort = {city_name_sort : 1};
$scope.orderProperty = '1';
$scope.helpers({
  city: function(){
    return City.find({});
  }
});
```

but it takes a long time to load and its make chrome stop working.

Comment: Maybe paginate on the server? so you will send only the information you display from the server?  also, maybe sure that when the search is empty, don't send all the results back

Comment: Normally with an auto-complete on a large collection you perform the search on the server and return only the matching records. Publishing all the data to the client is going to be slow. You could restrict the number of fields you are publishing to just the one field you are auto-completing on.

Comment: Thanks for sharing idea actually now pagination help to not break the browser but its take time to load all data but @MichelFloyd I realy don,t how to search on server .
mean while I hear about onReady but I cannot make it happen because I have 1 page for loading I would like to load data before page load .
could you help me for any refrence for these 2 : onReady & search on server?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You already have most of the server-side searching done because your search is running inside a subscription. You should make sure that the `city_name` field is indexed in mongo! You should only return that field to minimize data transfer. You can also simplify your regex.

```
Meteor.publish('city', function (searchString) {
  const re = new RegExp(searchString,'i');
  const where = { city_name: { $regex: re }};
  return City.find(where, {sort: {city_name: 1}, fields: {city_name: 1}});
});
```

What I've found helps with server-side auto-complete is:

1. Don't start searching until the user has typed 3 or 4 characters. This drastically narrows down the search results.
2. Throttle the search to only run every 500ms so that you're not sending every character to the server because then it has to keep re-executing the search. If the person is typing fast the search might only run every 2 or 3 characters.
3. Run the same `.find()` on the client that you're running on the server (instead of just querying for `{}`). That's just good practice since the client-side collection is the union of all subscriptions on that collection, there might be documents there that you don't want to list.

Lastly I don't know why you're subscribing twice here:

```
subscriptions: function () {
  Meteor.subscribe('city');
  this.register('city', Meteor.subscribe('city'));
}
```

only one of those `Meteor.subscribe('city')` calls is necessary.

Comment: Dear @Michel Floyd thanks for reply and sorry for typo issue I change Public as your suggestion and change to 500ms and minimum 3 characters and ad index
 `if ( Meteor.isServer ) {
  City._ensureIndex( { city_name: 1 } );
} `
and add Schema :
`City = new Mongo.Collection('city');
  var Schemas = {};
 Schemas.City = new SimpleSchema({
  city_name : {
    type: String
  }`
and regex to helpers but nothing return to client side and `City.find().fetch()` return empty array.
again sorry for my newby mistakes

Comment: See mods to regex to use, mongodb is a bit particular about that.